# Problems profiling java app remotely using VisualVM 1.3.8 on AWS EMR/EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, profiling, visualvm

I'm trying to profile an application remotely.  VisualVM appears to be a good tool, currently I'm using version 1.3.8.  I've installed it on my local machine.

The app I need to profile is on an Amazon EMR cluster - I'm using the Master EC2 node to connect. (I think this is correct)

I've followed a small tutorial [Tut](http://www.codefactorycr.com/java-visualvm-to-profile-a-remote-server.html) and made some progress.  I added the ports to the security group so they are open and then checked this using a web interface.  VisualVM wouldn't connect.  I then disabled iptables on the ec2 instance thnking perhaps there were still some firewall issues but still unabel to connect.

When I run the jstad command from the terminal there is no feedback -I'm not sure if there should be, it doesn't error but just sits there.

command is: `./jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy`
 where the policy is one form the tutorial, without this I received a write exception.

I'd very much like to get this working and any help is hugely appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Instead of trying it over internet, try it with the SSH tunnel.

Comment: @11thdimension - not sure what you mean..try what with the tunnel?  Checking that the port is open?

Comment: I mean you can try connecting JMX over SSH, then there would be one less configuration (Jstatd) to figure out.